# Use Powershell to extract PEM file lines add quotes to beginning and end and make it one line

Tags: regex, string, powershell, pem

How do I take the contents of a .PEM that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK
XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx
mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe
jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ
HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW
qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO
wwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To make it look like this as one line:

```
"k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK" "XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx" "mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe" "jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ" "HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW" "qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO" "bwIDAQAB"
```

I'm able to remove the Begin and End lines using the following:

```
    $File = "C:\pathto\some.pem"
    $content = Get-Content $file
    $contents =  $content
    
    $Complete = [regex]::split($contents, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----(.*?)-----END PUBLIC KEY-----")
    
    for($i = 1; $i -lt $Complete.Length; $i =$i+2){
        $Complete[$i] -replace " ","`r`n"
    }
```

Comment: You are doing things backwards.  You have 6 lines and want to make 1 line.  So you want to remove the return characters, not add them.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The quotes in your expected output appear to be mismatched  - you’ve got one at the start of the string (```”k=rsa```) which is closed by the one at the end of the first ```p``` value (```p=MIIB…VudK”```) - is this correct, or a typo?

Comment: k=rsa; is not even in the original string. Plus you have the string broken up at random points without any explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

First, some caveats:

- As noted in comments, the quotes in your expected output appear to be mismatched - you’ve got one at the start of the string (`"k=rsa`) which is closed by the one at the end of the first p value (`p=MIIB...VudK"`).  I'm not sure if this is a typo or if this is the expected output, so I'm going to take it at face value and assume it's the expected output. You might need to  adapt this answer slightly if it's a typo.
- Also the last line of your PEM *data* in the question is `wwIDAQAB` but your example output ends with `"bwIDAQAB"` - one starts with `w` and the other starts with `b` - I'm going to assume this is a typo and I'll use the value starting with `b` to match the expected output.

---

#### Answer

`Get-Content` returns an *array* of strings which is equivalent to this:

```
$content = @(
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----",
    "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK",
    "XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx",
    "mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe",
    "jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ",
    "HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW",
    "qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO",
    "bwIDAQAB",
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
);
```

(note I've changed the last data line to `bwIDAQAB` to match your expected output).

And just for completeness here's your expected output:

```
$expected = '"k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK" "XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx" "mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe" "jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ" "HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW" "qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO" "bwIDAQAB"'
```

This snippet will do what you're after (with the above caveats):

```
$complete = @(
    "`"k=rsa; p=",
    ($content[1..($content.Length - 2)] -join "`" `""),
    "`""
) -join ""

$complete -eq $expected
# True
```

which basically:

- starts with a `"k=rsa; p=` prefix
- throws away the first and last line of the PEM input
- joins the remaining lines with a literal `" "` separator
- adds a `"` suffix

to give:

```
"k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK" "XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx" "mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe" "jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ" "HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW" "qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO" "bwIDAQAB"
```

If you prefer not ro use the [range operator (`..`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#range-operator-) you can do it with `select-object` instead:

```
$complete = @(
    "`"k=rsa; p=",
    (($content | select-object -Skip 1 -First ($content.Length - 2)) -join "`" `""),
    "`""
) -join ""

$complete -eq $expected
# True
```

which is a slightly more verbose way of doing the same thing.

---

#### Bonus Content

Your line:

```
$Complete = [regex]::split($contents, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----(.*?)-----END PUBLIC KEY-----")
```

is coercing the `$contents` *array* of strings into a single string because that's what `[regex]::Split` expects, which you can see if you execute `[regex]::Split` in a PowerShell session:

```
PS> [regex]::Split

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static string[] Split(string input, string pattern)
static string[] Split(string input, string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options)
static string[] Split(string input, string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options, timespan matchTimeout)
```

The first parameter in all three overloads is `string input`.

The default behaviour in PowerShell when "stringifying" an array of values is to concatenate their `.ToString()` results using a space separator. E.g.

```
PS> "$content"
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ6AMIIBCgKCAQEAse68c1suNUQr0d79VudK XgmNxggQoaqR9fZoCrUz/gRS5XZm9wDL9HHxjYjEhZsuXQw1SZpYggjRQuqE+7Nx mhgn6DXXjWiTZ2b/ScE9mu+RQyh4hWEk9u+uUD2MZ9oPUZi2tN43InH9Qduza1Fe jQeh6OW6Bg+fTsBXtPJWawF/3oMCdWVfZ8Iel0ilP+61B5ldkw7g//QMf5mqzvkQ HK5/gKPCfGUylRDtJOxOriM5XqCjgtw6Sye8hgql5DGOCZTrXAahNbnw0bGm5TYW qosD+B2Rh/Xa600j/X0JAABQ8Pi1b0PAycGdMW7HPQ1YAp5Q7PbQQxlmlWeHQEgO bwIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and that's what you're passing into the regex, in case you were wondering :-)...